After magento update from v. 2.4.3 to 2.4.7 checkout is not working properly. "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'form')" error message
After magento update from v. 2.4.3 to 2.4.7 checkout is not working properly. When I want to place the order every time I get this error message in the console from jquery.validate.js. :
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'form')" and this is the program code:
valid: function() {
            var valid, validator, errorList;
            if ( $( this[ 0 ] ).is( "form" ) ) {
                valid = this.validate().form();
            } else {
                errorList = [];
                valid = true;
                validator = $( this[ 0 ].form() ).validate();
                this.each( function() {
                    valid = validator.element( this ) && valid;
                    if ( !valid ) {
                        errorList = errorList.concat( validator.errorList );
                    }
                } );
                validator.errorList = errorList;
            }
            return valid;
        }  
                                                                                                                                                                                Can somebody help me with this problem?  


Have you check by disable all third party extension and then try?

@beata Hey, Hover on the error or click on that error in the console it will redirect you to the file that brings the error go to that file and check whether form is defined or not if the file is overridden in the theme then please match that file with the original file from the vendor. Thank You!
